# Incrementing Column A Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have been striving to create a solution that is Increment the Number. Where from `Column B` data is start that is `row 18` so code will copy value from the `Column A row 17` to the last row of `Column C` with incrementing the number.

I'm hoping you can help me with.

[image]

```
Sub IncrmentNumber()
    
    Dim ws          As Worksheet, LRow As Long, r As Long
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = 2 To LastRow
        
        If ws.Cells(r, "C") <> "" Then
            
            ws.Cells(r - 1, "A").Value = ws.Cells(r, "A").Value + 1
            
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Result will be like

[image]

Comment: So, the start to be considered the row keeping the first value in column B:B (KM)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want? Uses the `DataSeries` method.

```
Sub x()

Dim n As Long

n = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
If n = 1 Then Exit Sub

Range("A" & n - 1 & ":A" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).DataSeries

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Just to note that should probably check that column B has something in it too.

Comment: There is one problem that is when there is no value in the Column B it fills Column A till last row that is 1048575

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned. You could add `If n = rows.count Then Exit Sub`.